# Protecting Word Document without displaying protection pane

Tags: c#, ms-word

i want to lock active word 2007 document with c sharp Doc.Protect() function. After that i do not wants to display the protection pane while trying to edit the document. Is this possible ? please help me if anybody having solution.

Comment: If you want to change how Word works when editing a document, you'll need to write an add-in.

Comment: ya presently am doing by addin solution only. Is there any option is there to hide the protection pane

Comment: `CommandBars("Restrict Editing").Visible = False`

Comment: CommandBars() is of which class ? can you please tell..

Comment: Google is much faster than me. It's [Document.CommandBars](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.commandbars.aspx)

Comment: After adding Doc.CommandBars("Restrict Editing").Visible = False I am getting error Non Invocable member . can not be used like method.

Comment: My example was recorded VBA code. You'll have to use `[]` instead of `()` and `false` instead of `False` for C#

Comment: thank you. Program executed without error. still protect pane is visible while trying to edit the document.

Comment: I believe the command will have to be executed after the document has been loaded